# How to Assign States to Viewers of Django Web Application?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

### Problem Statement

I'm working on building out a single-page Django web app and am trying to implement the following functionality:
- All viewers of the page are associated with a state. There are buttons on the page which enable viewers to change their state.
- The application stores a list of all current viewers of the page, and their associated states. Whenever a user changes their state, this stored list of viewers updates with this new information.
- The application should display how many people are online (viewing the page) at a given time.

### Blockers

1. I'm unsure of how to collect a list of all current viewers of a page in Django, nor how to collect how many users are currently viewing the page.
2. Ideally, my application would not require a login to use: therefore, I'd rather either associate viewer state with a user object that doesn't require sign-in, or not associate viewer state with a user object (I'm still new to user objects though, so forgive me if this point doesn't make complete sense).

### What I'm Looking For

A discussion of higher-level strategies which I can use to implement this functionality, or other places to look to gain insight in tackling my problem. I'm pretty new to Django, so I'd appreciate it if answers also direct me to locations in my Django project which are of relevance (e.g. "Consider doing X in `views.py`, then..."). Alternatively, if there are GitHub projects you know of with similar functionality, if you could direct me to them to investigate further, that would also be appreciated.

I'd be happy to offer further clarification as required. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need to user websockets to communicate between front/back end in real time.. [django-channels](https://github.com/django/channels)

Comment: Thanks @bodoubleu! I can see how that helps with communicating viewer state - do you know how I should set up the viewer object to keep track of all current viewers of the page?